# Retrieving the senders name and email from an envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a service account that is using **DocuSign's *polling*** to retrieve a list of envelopes that had a status change. These envelopes were sent by various internal users. When I go to retrieve the envelopes, I'd like to retrieve who the sender of the envelope is (*sender's name and email*).

I initially excepted this information to be part of the `Envelope` object, but it's not:

```
Envelope envInfo = envelopesApi.GetEnvelope(AccountId, envelopeId);
```

I've tried various other API calls and reviewed documentation, but none of them seem to provide a way to get the sender's name and email.

Can this information be retrieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually is a way that you can get Sender Name and Email for an Envelope via the API. First, issue a **Get Envelope Audit Events** request to identify the `UserId` of the Sender. Then, use that `UserId` to issue a **Get User** request to obtain the sender's name and email address. Here are the steps, with sample requests/responses (irrelevant info omitted, for brevity):

**1) Get Envelope Audit Events**

Request:

```
GET /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/audit_events
```

Response:

```
{
    "auditEvents": [
        {
            "eventFields": [
                ...
                {
                    "name": "UserName",
                    "value": "John Doe"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UserId",
                    "value": "af465e97-83a6-472c-a25b-ebad10e4cc6a"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Action",
                    "value": "Registered"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Message",
                    "value": "The envelope was created by John Doe"
                },
                {
                    "name": "EnvelopeStatus",
                    "value": "created"
                },
                ...
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

**2) Get User** (specifying the `UserId` from the previous response)

Request:

```
 GET /accounts/{accountId}/users/af465e97-83a6-472c-a25b-ebad10e4cc6a
```

Response:

```
{
    "userName": "John Doe",
    "userId": "af465e97-83a6-472c-a25b-ebad10e4cc6a",
    "email": "john.doe@test.com",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    ...
}
```

Another option (if you're creating the Envelopes with the API to begin with) would be to always specify "Custom Envelope Fields" for each Envelope at creation-time that contain the sender's name and email address. Doing it this way would let you retrieve this info with the same request you're already issuing to retrieve the envelope info (provided that you include the extra querystring parameter (`include=custom_fields`):

```
GET accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}?include=custom_fields
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign does not work in this way, as envelopes are linked to a user and its user's documents so no one can access the document until and unless user shares the envelopes with anyone. So there are no APIs which will inform you the sender email/name by querying DS on envelopeId. You have two ways to achieve this requirement:

- Use DS Connect (recommended way), configure Connect in your DS
  Account and DocuSign will push the connect messages with the sender
  details in that XML message when a subscribed trigger event occurs
- Another way is you need to get OAUTH access token of all your users and
  then call DS APIs to know the envelopes for each user

Connect message will look like below:

```
<UserName>Sender Name</UserName>
<Email>SenderEmail@email.com</Email>
```